# Why are models sometimes referred to in lowercase in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-signals

I am having trouble understand this line of code:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

Why is profile lowercase in `instance.profile.save()`?

The code works, I read through the Django docs trying to find the answer, but I can't. This actually made my project work completely, but I don't use things I don't understand.

My model looks like this:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.FileField(default='No_picture_available.png')
    School = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
    Profession = models.CharField(max_length=90, null=True)
    Bio = models.TextField(max_length=500,null=True)
    FullName = models.CharField(max_length=80, null=True)
    age = models.IntegerField(null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile
```

Comment: Since the `sender` is `User`, I'm guessing that the `User` object has a `profile` attribute. The `instance` is likely a `User` object, which is why this works.

Comment: yeah wouldn't that be the Class profile. Profile is captial

Comment: You have defined `user` as a `OneToOneField`. When you do this, it creates an attribute in the referenced class, in this case, `User`. Have a read on the usage of OneToOneField: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/

Comment: Additionally, the Python convention is to use `lowercase` variables names everywhere. `PascalCase` is reserved for class names et al.

Comment: so it just takes my "class profile" and lowercase it????? since user is extending the user model?

Comment: Please, share the code of model **Profile**

Comment: its already printed in the question.